# Run Python module from another directory

Tags: python, module, terminal

I'm running my Python module like this: `python -m py_projects.my_module.my_submodule`
This is working pretty wel in case I'm in my PYthon project folder. But how can i run my module in case I'm not in my project folder.
Was trying something like this:

```
python /home/pi/Desktop/Projects -m py_projects.my_module.my_submodule
```

But I got only error: no main module was found.

Comment: Either change the working directory to `/home/pi/Desktop/Projects` or add it to the `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: I'm trying to put this command line into the CRON. So I need only one line I guess...

Comment: Then you could do `cd /home/pi/Desktop/Projects && python -m py_projects.my_module.my_submodule`

Comment: Thanks, no idea about &&.

Comment: Why do you want to *run* from another directory?  Do you want the script to  act on things in the other directory?

Comment: The CRON needs absolute directory or?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your python file *hello.py* in Projects Directory

Simply Run:

```
python Desktop/Projects/hello.py
```